# Quitar "triángulo" en ventana pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt

quiero saber si existe una forma de eliminar el triángulo que muestro a continuación en una ventana, estuve buscando pero no encontré.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de la construcción de la ventana:

```
class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VentanaPrincipal, self).__init__()
        loadUi('principal.ui', self)
        #self.setWindowTitle("A")
        #self.agregar_cliente.clicked.connect(self.abrir_agregar_cliente)
        #self.ver_cliente.clicked.connect(self.abrir_vcliente)
        #self.find_car.clicked.connect(self.abrir_registros)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = VentanaPrincipal()
main.show()
app.setStyle('Fusion')
palette = QtGui.QPalette()
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(53,53,53))
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, QtCore.Qt.white)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtGui.QColor(15,15,15))
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, QtGui.QColor(53,53,53))
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, QtCore.Qt.white)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, QtCore.Qt.white)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QtCore.Qt.white)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QtGui.QColor(53,53,53))
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, QtCore.Qt.white)
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, QtCore.Qt.red)   
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QtGui.QColor(142,45,197).lighter())
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, QtCore.Qt.black)
app.setPalette(palette)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún código al respecto? Sin código no se puede detectar el problema

Comment: Parece que ese triángulo es un "handle" para cambiar de tamaño la ventana. Tal vez si das con alguna opción para que la ventana tenga tamaño fijo desaparezca. (¿Quizás `setFixedSize()`?)

Comment: @n1ck, *No creo que sea necesario adjuntar código, es algo de Qt me parece amigo.* -> Primero, ***SIEMPRE*** suele ser necesario adjuntar código, pues estás programando y haciendo preguntas de programación. Y segundo, no hagas una afirmación añadiendo *me parece*, si *te parece* es que no estás seguro, así que mejor añade el código tal y como se indica en [ask] y en el [tour], por favor. Las preguntas tienen un formato y se debe respetar para que podamos ayudarte. Esa imagen no nos dice absolutamente nada de lo que has hecho para construir la ventana, con lo cual no sabemos qué pasa!!

Comment: @Benito-B ahí edité la publicación, perdón, soy nuevo en este lugar..

Comment: @n1ck prueba con `main.statusBar().setSizeGripEnabled(False)`

Comment: @eyllanesc ty, +10